# Shaped views in react-native

Tags: react-native

How do I get the the rounded `view` like that? I've been messing around with `borderRadius`, but it's not getting how I wanted...

In short, I put a `<View>` around my `<Image>`, made that one bigger than the screen and started to change `borderBottomRadius` and set it to `overflow:hidden`

It looks very clumsy now, not beautifully rounded

```
<View style={Styles.border}>
  <Image></Image>
</View>
```

**Style**:

```
  border:{
    flex:1,
    width: width + 300,
    left:-150,
    top:0,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:width -100,
    borderBottomRightRadius:width - 100,
    overflow:'hidden'
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This is not worthy of an answer, because it doesn't solve the problem in code, but I would just place a half-transparent image on top of the image and be done with it.

Comment: That's either way a nice alternative if I'm out of ideas, so thanks ;)